# In Django, disable @login_required for search engine spiders

Tags: django, seo, web-crawler, googlebot, login-required

I'm looking for a clean way to let search engine spiders bypass @login_required, viewing pages which typically require a logged-in user.  I could write middleware that would automatically log search engines into a dummy account, but that's not exactly what I'd call clean.  Any suggestions for a better solution?  Thanks.

Comment: It would help to clarify why you want to do this. For example, if you are providing full-text access that you want to be searchable on Google Scholar but not to the general user, I believe that you can do this without getting banned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this. This is 'cloaking', and can get you banned from Google's index.

> Cloaking refers to the practice of presenting different content or URLs to users and search engines. Serving up different results based on user agent may cause your site to be perceived as deceptive and removed from the Google index.

- Cloaking: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66355

Instead, you need to implement Google's **First Click Free** solution. In this setup, the first click from a Google search result is able to see the full content, subsequent clicks are trapped. This can be done on a referrer basis, or a cookie basis. You can read more about First Click Free here:

- First Click Free: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=74536

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do this? If search engines can see the pages, then anyone can see them without being logged in, because the information would surface on the search engine's results page. In any case, the only way to identify a spider or bot is by its user agent string, which is trivial to spoof.

Comment: Trivial for us, but not for my users, who are both non-technical and also typically institutional (and therefore averse to even trivial rule breaking in many cases).

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. in "@login_required" you have an important word: "required". if it's "required", it's for a good reason. It means that, in order to see the webpage, your credentials are mandatory. Because the content is private, secret, etc.

If you want to make your pages to be available via search engines, you have to make them public, and thus, login is *not* required anymore. And so, your view should not be protected by the @login_required decorator.

Maybe your problem lies beyond the availabilty of your pages. Maybe your content is *actually* made to be public, and your views should not be protected by this decorator. Maybe the only thing you need is to load the public part for every user (logged or anonymous) and eventually load the private bits if your user is identified.

Otherwise, leaving a backdoor for spiders is definitely a bad idea, because your private content won't be private anymore.